# GeoIP for Laravel 4 shows only example data

Tags: laravel-4, geoip

I have installed GeoIP ([Torann/laravel-4-geoip](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-4-geoip)) with Laravel 4. I have downloaded the MaxMind [GeoLite2 City](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) mmdb data file and placed it in app/database/maxmind as instructed.

My basic code is below but it always displays the example data rather than actual values.

```
$loc = GeoIP::getLocation();
print_r($loc);
```

And every time I get this back:

```
Array ( [ip] => ::1 [isoCode] => US [country] => United States [city] => New Haven [state] => CT [postal_code] => 06510 [lat] => 41.31 [lon] => -72.92 [timezone] => America/New_York [continent] => NA [default] => 1 )
```

I made no changes to the config file, it still reads like so:

```
return array(

  // Service (only maxmind so far)
  'service' => 'maxmind',

  'maxmind' => array(
    'type'          => 'database', // database or web_service
    'user_id'       => '',
    'license_key'   => ''
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bogdan figured this out for me - I was doing quick testing in the template before I moved it into the Model and passed it through the Controller. Once i moved it things started to work.

Using just 
    GeoIP::getLocation(); 
on my local server doesn't work so what I'm doing now is testing with this:

```
$ip  = '173.234.149.140';  //la
$loc = \GeoIP::getLocation($ip);
```

Once on a live server I should be able to get the actual IP from the client. Ultimately I'm pulling the lat and long, and finding the closest store location from my own database of store locations then using a Haversine mySQL formula to find the closest like so:

```
$lat = $loc['lat'];
$lng = $loc['lon'];
$results = \DB::select( \DB::raw("SELECT  id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < 500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;"));
```

Comment: Will it work on localhost?? or need a live server to run this code?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `getLocation` method requires you to pass an IP address and it will return the location details of that IP. For example using this IP address that belongs to Google:

```
GeoIP::getLocation('64.233.191.128');
```

You would get this data back:

```
array(
  "ip"          => "64.233.191.128"
  "isoCode"     => "US"
  "country"     => "United States"
  "city"        => "Mountain View"
  "state"       => "CA"
  "postal_code" => 94043
  "lat"         => 37.4192
  "lon"         => -122.0574
  "default"     => false
)
```

#### NOTE

Calling `GeoIP::getLocation()` without an IP will not work when testing on a local server because the local IP is not public.

Comment: According to the documentation it sounds like using just GeoIP::GetLocation() will 'Get the location data for a website visitor' - so I didn't think you had to pass it an IP. When I try using GeoIP::getLocation('64.233.191.128') - with an IP address, even that one exactly, there is no response and no error. Weird thing is it doesn't even complete any other code within the same php script delimiters.

Comment: Are you testing this locally on your by any chance?

Comment: I'm testing on my local machine using XAMPP

Comment: Well that's your problem then, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` can't return any valid data because it's not a public IP address, and that's the IP that GeoIP tries to get the data for when you call it without an IP address.

Comment: But it should work if I supply an ip address, shouldn't it? If use GeoIP::getLocation('64.233.191.128'); for example? Even running locally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64520/discussion-between-bogdan-and-dylan-glockler).